# Rename nested keys of array

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I need change values of nested arrays to use plugin

https://github.com/khan4019/tree-grid-directive

My JSON looks like this:

```
[{"Id":13,"Name":"sadas","Users":[],"Managers":[],"Departments":[{"Id":14,"Name":"hgjghjghjg","Users":[],"Managers":[],"Departments":[{"Id":16,"Name":"kjk","Users":[],"Managers":[],"Departments":[{"Id":17,"Name":"vcxv","Users":[],"Managers":[],"Departments":[]}]}]},{"Id":15,"Name":"p[op[","Users":[],"Managers":[],"Departments":[]}]}]
```

To use angular plugin need rename every key `Departments to children`, and remove `""` from keys.

I try to use Json.stringify, and replace like in default string

```
var objToSend = JSON.stringify(response.Departments);
var str = objToSend.replace("\"Departments\":", "\"children\":");
$rootScope.tree_data = str;
```

but its no worked for me, its just change first key of array, but not nested and return

```
[{"Id":13,"Name":"sadas","Users":[],"Managers":[],"children":[{"Id":14,"Name":"hgjghjghjg","Users":[],"Managers":[],"Departments":[{"Id":16,"Name":"kjk","Users":[],"Managers":[],"Departments":[{"Id":17,"Name":"vcxv","Users":[],"Managers":[],"Departments":[]}]}]},{"Id":15,"Name":"p[op[","Users":[],"Managers":[],"Departments":[]}]}]
```

Comment: Hi Welcome to StackOverflow. Unfortunately, this is not a code writing service, you need to attempt something yourself and ask specific questions should you have difficulty.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your replace method wont work as replace only changes the first occurrence. You could do it with a regex however.

Or (in my opinion) better still you could do a nested `map` using [array.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

Something like this

```
function rename (obj) {
  for(var prop in obj) {

    if (Array.isArray(obj[prop])) {
        obj[prop] = obj[prop].map(rename);
    }

    if (prop === 'Departments') {
      obj.children = obj[prop];
      delete obj[prop];
    }
  }

    return obj;
};

var y = x.map(rename);
```

However this will only recursively check arrays. Not nested object properties. However looking at your data it only appears to be arrays.

This will not work for a structure like this for example.

```
var data = {
  "Id": 17,
  "Name": "vcxv",
  "Users": [],
  "Managers": [],
  "Departments": {
    "Id": 18,
    "Name": "trollol",
    "Users": [],
    "Managers": [],
    "Departments": {}
  }
};
```

demo fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/f90uh9ou/

---

EDIT: Update, you could also use `Object.keys` to get the objects keys in an array. Not too sure if there's any benefit here however over `for in` may even be a performance hit. `Object.keys` is more useful in function composition and method chaining and such.

But here's an updated fiddle for the hell of it. https://jsfiddle.net/f90uh9ou/1/